# Float div to the left while keeping it's "left" css property

Tags: javascript, css

so as the title says i need to float my div with absolute position to the left while keeping `left: 100px` or whatever it's set to, for example let's say i have these rules:

```
.myDiv{
     position:absolute;
     left:100px;
     top:100px;
     width:50px;
     height:50px;
}
```

Now how can i `float` it to the left side which would be `left:0px` without using this `left` command, i need something similar to `float:left` also `javascript` is totaly acceptable.

And if any one is wondering why i need this quite strange thing is because i want to keep this object offset so later i could bring it back to it's original position.

Comment: what about padding-left?

Comment: If you're okay with Javascript, then I think you are trying to solve the wrong problem. Maybe giving more information about what exactly you want will help us help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do this. Absolutely positioned objects can only be moved by changing one or more of `left`, `top`, `bottom`, `right` (or relocating them inside the DOM tree).

If you want to be able to move the element to a previous position, save the value of `left` somewhere so that you can restore it when the time comes. It's easy to do and will be by itself enough to accomplish almost anything you will want it to.

Comment: OP didn't say he wouldn't be fine with changing `position` temporarily

Comment: @NiklasB.: There's only so much you can do by just changing `position`. I really do not think it's going to be enough, and in any case we 'd need the exact markup and a detailed specification of what he's attempting.

Comment: just as i thought, oh well i guess i will have to save old position with `js` and use it when i need it